Playwright: Unable to capture URL address of a new tab in headless mode
The test fails in headless mode, but when mode is headless: false test passed.
await productAttachment.element.click();    // this action opens a new page with a pdf attachment

const newPage = await page.waitForEvent('popup');
await expect(newPage).toHaveURL(expectedAddressURL);

I also tried using the version with:
await context.waitForEvent('page');

but it behaves the same.
I have already tried many solutions but nothing helps.
Logs:

Received string: "about:blank"
    Call log:
      - expect.toHaveURL with timeout 10000ms
      - waiting for locator(':root')
      -   locator resolved to <html>…</html>
      -   unexpected value "about:blank"

Environment:

@playwright/test: ^1.44.0
Operating System: Windows
Node.js version: v20.12.2
Browser: chromium


What site are you automating? Please share a [mcve].

Please elaborate, which solutions you have tried

Handling pdf in headed and headless need different approaches
see https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/6342
Below is example test. Remember to set consts.
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';

const url = ;
const linkToPdf = ;
const pdfUrl = ;

test('verify link in new tab in headless', async ({ page, browserName, headless, context }) => {
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.locator(linkToPdf).first().click();
   
    // start waiting for new tab
    const newTabPromise = page.waitForEvent('popup');

    // check if browser is chromium and headless is true and handle it
    // https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/6342
    if (browserName === 'chromium' && headless === true) {
        const [download] = await Promise.all([
            page.waitForEvent('download'), // wait for download to start
            page.getByLabel('fileName').click(),
        ]);
        const endsWithPdf = download.suggestedFilename().endsWith('.pdf');
        expect(endsWithPdf).toBe(true);
    }
    else if ((browserName === 'chromium' && headless === false) || browserName === 'firefox' || browserName === 'webkit') {
        await page.getByLabel('fileName').click();
        const newTab = await newTabPromise;
        newTab.on('response', response =>
            expect(response.headers()['content-type']).toBe('application/pdf')
        );
        await newTab.waitForURL(pdfUrl);
    }

});

